# Botpress User Interface - exporting a Bot

Tags: node-modules, chatbot, packaging

I am new to using botpress and recently downloaded the botpress community edition.
I have started using the botpress community edition to create bots but they only work in the Admin UI console , how do i export them as modules or packages which can be used ?

The Admin UI isnt creating the index.js files under the data/<> directory and hence i am stuck.

Comment: Hi did you have any luck with this?